# Acceder al HttpContext.Session en ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hola estoy creando una app en **asp.net core 2.1** y necesito obtener una variable de sesión en una clase **no Controller** pero al agregar:  `HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionVar")` me saca el error:

> "Se requiere una referencia de objeto para el campo,método o propiedad
>   'HttpContext.Session' no estáticos"

he intentado de varias formas pero no se me da.

Comment: Hola, edita por favor la pregunta, e indica el error que te da. También indica el código de la clase donde accedes a la sesión.

Comment: Puedes indicar también lo que tienes en el archivo **Startup.cs** ?. Allí debes tener definidos los servicios para usar Sesiones en ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

En principio, debes tener configurados los servicios para usar **sesiones** en ASP.NET Core en el archivo **`Startup.cs`**:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(); 
        // AÑADIR LOS SERVICIOS DE SESIÓN.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options => {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); // Tiempo de expiración   
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // AÑADIR LA SESIÓN.
        // DEBE IR SIEMPRE ANTES DE app.UseMvc
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Luego, para acceder a la sesión desde una **clase NO controladora**, debes hacerlo mediante **inyección de dependencias** en el constructor de la clase, a través de la interfaz **`IHttpContextAccessor`**:

```
public class MiClase
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MiClase(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void PruebaSet()
    {
        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionVar", "Prueba!");
    }

    public void PruebaGet()
    {
        var message = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionVar");
    }
}
```

Comment: he seguido tus indicaciones para crear una variable de sesión, y me surge una duda. Cuando instancio la clase en una clase mía, concretamente en un index.cshtml.cs en el evento onGet, puedo dar valores a la variable de sesión y recojerlos con el pruebaGet y PruebaSet. Mi intención es que estos datos estén disponibles en otra pantalla, donde cuando vuelvo a instanciar MiClase e intento recojer el valor de la variable de sessión me retorna un null. He probado a añadir el servicio de tipo singleton pero no funciona. No se si es que estoy haciendo algo mal. Muchas gracias.